# How to not restart a systemd service, when the service it depends on is restarted

Tags: linux, systemd, services, postgresql

Let's say I have a service that depends on postgresql:
I have it set up with the following directives

```
After=postgresql.service
Requisite=postgresql.service
```

When I restart postgresql the above service also gets restarted. I would like for it to not get restarted, but maybe stop running if the restart on postgresql fails.

Comment: Please update the question with a more realistic example that can be used for reproducing it, such as the ones you mentioned in the comments using `sleep infinity`. Currently, the question doesn't have enough context and is using a `Requisite=` directive which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **Requires** ?

**Requires** : Configures requirement dependencies on other services. If this service gets activated, the units listed here are activated too. If one of the dependent services fails to activate, systemd does not start this service. This option may be specified more than once or you can specify multiple space-separated units. Below is sample unit section.

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
Requires=network.target
```

**Wants** : Similar to Requires, except failed units do not have any effect on the service.

**BindsTo** : Similar to Requires, except stopping the dependent units also stops the service.

**PartOf** : Similar to Requires, except the stopping and restarting dependent units also stop and restart the service.

Reference : https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/understanding-and-administering-systemd/

Comment: Yes, I have.
Restarting postgresql again restarts the service that  Requires it. 
I am guessing this happens because there is a moment during the restart process, in which the postgresql service is not active (running).

Comment: @BoyanAtanasov That's not how systemd works, it will not restart services that require Postgres if you restart Postgres. It is possible that one or more of the services that depend on it are exiting once it goes down, in which case systemd will bring them up again if configured to do so. Maybe that's what you're experiencing?

Comment: This is my "main" service:  
```[Unit]  
Description=<descirption>  
  
[Service]  
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity  
  
[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target  
```  
  This is my dependent "service"    
```[Unit]  
Description=<description>  
  
Requires="main".service  
  
[Service]  
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/sleep infinity"  
```  

Restarting the "main service" using systemctl restart "main" also restarts the "dependent" service.

Comment: @filbranden  
Yes because they require that postgresql is active they go down when i restart postgresql because there is a brief moment in which postgresql is not active during its restart.  
Thus I am looking for a way when i restart postgresql, to not stop and start the services that depend on it.